# how to retrieve the data from two table in mysql database with if condition in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, for-loop

[image: table design]

my code is

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;border:1px solid blue;"> 
<div style="width:400px;height:50px; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
<form>
<div align="right" style="width:150px;height:30px; float: left;">Show Name :&nbsp;    </div>
<div style="width:250px;height:30px; float: left;">
<select name="show_name" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option selected="selected"> -- Select The Show --</option>
<?php   
session_start();
include_once('db.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT show_id, show_name FROM show_name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$show_id = $row['show_id'];
$show_name= $row['show_name'];
echo "<option value ='.$show_id'>$show_name</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div align="right" style="width:150px;height:30px; float: left;">Show Place :&nbsp;      </div>
<div style="width:250px;height:30px; float: left;">
<select name="show_place" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option selected="selected"> -- Select The Show Place --</option>
<?php   
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM show_name, show_place WHERE    show_name.show_id=show_place.show_id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$show_id = $row['show_id'];
$show_place = $row['show_place'];
echo "<option value ='.$show_id'>$show_place</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

i want to option box condition for stud show to select the particular place .. please guide me how to merge the two table by using if condition or foreach condition

Comment: I think you want the places box to be filtered by the selection of the shows box?

Comment: also, you do a session_start after output has already begun. this should be before any output

Comment: You should try to start your questions with a short question statement up front. Starting with data and code blocks without any explanation makes for hard reading. That said, an example of expected output would help this question a lot.

Comment: hi nvanesch i m using dependent table for 4 combo box and i got three combo dependent table correct but 4th one is making more and more trouble

Answer (score 0):

for strict matches:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM show_name
    JOIN show_place ON (show_name.show_id = show_place.show_id)
```

Or if you want names without places too:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM show_name
    LEFT JOIN show_place ON (show_name.show_id = show_place.show_id)
```